# Collecting a twitter data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, tweepy

I am trying to get a twitter data set where users share their opinion(+ve/-ve) about a particular topic.Whether it can be discussion about movies/mobiles or any other topic.How/where can i get this dataset?.I am trying to analyse the opinion dynamics of users who participated in the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has an API for downloading tweets and the related properties. With it you can pretty much get wathever you like from the tweets with the limitations of the data that are offered by the AP9 itself (https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to an implementation of twitter streaming api.
http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the [official twitter api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview), I would suggest take a look at [Awesome Twitter Data](https://github.com/shaypal5/awesome-twitter-data) repository which contains links to different twitter dataset available to download.